# Python random method

Tags: python, random, methods

How can i here `rgb_im = com4.convert('RGB')` random method replace com4 with another? for example com3, or com2 or com1.
I tried several variations but none worked.

`com1 = Image.alpha_composite(im1, im2)`

`com2 = Image.alpha_composite(com1, im3)`

`com3 = Image.alpha_composite(com2, im4)`

`com4 = Image.alpha_composite(com3, im5)`

`#Convert to RGB`

`rgb_im = com4.convert('RGB')`

`file_name = str(item["tokenId"]) + ".png"`

`rgb_im.save("./images/" + file_name)`

Comment: Would `random.choice([com1, com2, com3, com4]).convert('RGB')` work?

Comment: Yes, it works. I forgot one parenthesis. Thank you very much @j1-lee